# How are the catenary curve, hyperbolic functions (cosh/sinh) and natural log related?

Tags: logarithms, conic-sections, math-history, curves, hyperbolic-functions

I understand that $\cosh(x)$ traces the catenary curve and points $(\cosh(t), \sinh(t))$ give points on a unit hyperbola. And the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$ is the basis of the curve for the natural log.

What I am struggling with is the proving their equivalence with one another, from a historical point of view, without using modern calculus. I want to *derive these proofs* myself for the sake of clarity, but haven't found any good reference/source to aid in the matter.

1. I know $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\cdot \sin\theta$. Algebraic manipulation allows me to come up with *definitions* of $\cosh\theta$ and $\sinh\theta$ as $\frac{(e^x \pm e^{-x})}{2(i)}$. How do I prove that these points lie on a hyperbola? This manipulation provides me a definition but not a proof.
2. Riccati's derivation of hyperbolic functions predates that of the definition above. Although this [page](http://www.faculty.fairfield.edu/jmac/sj/scientists/riccati.htm) tries to explain it, the figures are so bad I have no idea what's really happening and how were they hyperbolic functions *first discovered*. How do I go from here to their modern definition in #1 above?
3. Is there a relation between the above and the natural log? Sure looks like it. The area under the unit rectangular hyperbola gives the natural log like shown [here](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/maths-power-laws/0/steps/12152). Any way to tie this to the above or is it an independent result?
4. What's the proof that the graph of $\cosh\theta$ produces a catenary curve? How did we *accept* this proof initially? Saying that the equation graphs a catenary is one thing, but how was it *proved* to be a catenary? How do I tie #1-3 together into this?

Is it possible to develop an intuition of how all these concepts relate to each other, without resorting to calculus? I believe these discoveries predate Newtonian/Leibniz' Calculus - I'd like to trace my path through history just to get a more intuitive grasp of the evolution of these ideas and how they all fit together.

**PS**: It's alright if calculus is part of the solution - I'd prefer to know *if* it was possible to prove all this *without* calculus and if so how. Calculus, makes life easier but clouds the historical development/evolution/undertanding IMHO.

Comment: See [Catenary](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Catenary.html) and [Catenary: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#History). The "discovery" does not predate calculus: without it, Galileo conjectured that a hanging cord is an approximate parabola.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409) explaining the connection between the natural logarithm and hyperbolic sine and cosine. (BTW, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/451372/409) gives geometric interpretations of all the trig functions.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to define the hyperbolic functions without calculus.
I've seen the derivation of the definitions of sinhx and coshx. It's around 5 pages worth and starts off with the area under a hyperbola.
If you wish to see this derivation let me know.

Comment: I'd make this answer a comment

Comment: @PhD people with too few reputation points are not allowed to comment.