# Can the hyperbolic cotangent be defined in terms of the projection of an intersection?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

We seem to be able to define most other trigonometric functions, including the hyperbolic tangent function visually, in terms of a geometric projection.

Is it possible to define the hyperbolic cotangent in a similar geometric way?

Comment: Related: ["Geometric construction of hyperbolic trigonometric functions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451034/409). In particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/451372/409) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I was confused because I didn’t consider the tangent of the conjugate hyperbole. Upvoted but it’ll only be visible when I reach 15 rep. :)