# What are Hyperbolic Trig Functions Functions of?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Circular trig functions take in an angle and spit out a ratio. What do hyperbolic  functions take in (I know it's a number, but what geometrically does it represent)?

I've seen images that suggest they're a function of area, and others describe $(\cosh(t),\sinh(t))$ as a parametric, which makes me think that t is arc length covered as you move along the unit hyperbola, just like how with a circular parametric trig function t can be interpreted as arc length. It seems like it should be the function of an angle, but it isn't.

Comment: In relativity, the parameter $\zeta$ in the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \cosh \zeta & \sinh\zeta \\ \sinh\zeta & \cosh \zeta\end{bmatrix}$ is called *rapidity*. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity) (notice that my $\zeta$ is that page's $w$). HTH

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the arc length, but it *is* the area between the hyperbola, the ray from the origin to the point, and the $x$-axis. Which is also true for the usual trigonometric functions on the circle. See [Wikipedia's discussion of hyperbolic angles and circular angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_angle#Comparison_with_circular_angle) for more.

Comment: From physics: the shape of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary is described by $\cosh (\bullet)$.

Comment: @Rahul I was about to post that as an answer, but since you commented it first I will leave it for you

Comment: I wonder what you really want to know. Why do you expect the input to $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ to have special meaning? I assume because they are named similarily to $\sin$ and $\cos$ which seem to have special meaning for their input. But the names are more for historical reasons and that they emerge from similar considerations. $\sin$ and $\cos$ more or less coincidentally work well with angles. One can try to define "hyperbolic angles" or find geometric interpretations for the inputs to $\sinh$/$\cosh$, but it is more artificial and more driven by the similar names than necessity/geometry.

Comment: @Chase No, go for it.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Alternative definition of hyperbolic cosine without relying on exponential function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757091/409) and ["Geometric construction of hyperbolic trigonometric functions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451034/409).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Is that matrix supposed to have some negative signs in there?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor: On the Wikipedia page they write $\begin{bmatrix} \cosh w & -\sinh w \\ -\sinh w & \cosh w\end{bmatrix}$. If you put $w=-\zeta$ you find the matrix of my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

The connecting factor amongst the hyperbolic and circular functions and the unit circle and hyperbola is not the *angle* subtended by the curve but rather the **area** bounded by it. Here are two images I pulled from the internet:

[image: hyperbola]
[image: hyperbola & circle]

Consider the point $\mathrm H(\cosh w, \sinh w)$ on the unit hyperbola and the point $\mathrm C(\cos z, \sin z)$ on the unit circle, both plotted on the $xy$-plane. Then

- $w$ equals twice the area bounded by $\rm OH$, the hyperbola, and the $x$-axis,

and since the area of the unit circle is $\pi(1)^2=\pi$, then

- $z$ equals twice the area bounded by $\rm OC$, the circle, and the $x$-axis.

> So to summarize, the relationship amongst the argument $t$ of any of the aforementioned functions and the area $a$ bounded by their characteristic locus is $t=2a$.

---

You mention “arc length covered as you move along the unit hyperbola.” Let’s consider the integral formula for arc length

$$L = \int_\alpha^\beta\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt$$

and compare the arc length $L(\mathrm H(T))$ traced along the unit hyperbola from point $(1,0)$ to $(\cosh T, \sinh T)$ and the arc length $L(\mathrm C(T))$ traced along the unit circle from point $(1,0)$ to $(\cos T, \sin T)$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm H 
&: \begin{cases} x=\cosh t \\ y=\sinh t\end{cases} \\[2ex]
&: \begin{cases} {dx}/{dt} = \sinh t \\ {dy}/{dt} = \cosh t\end{cases}
\\[4ex]
\mathrm C 
&: \begin{cases} x=\cos t \\ y=\sin t\end{cases} \\[2ex]
&: \begin{cases} {dx}/{dt} = -\sin t \\ {dy}/{dt} = \cos t\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

So

$$L(\mathrm H(T)) = \int_0^T \sqrt{ \cosh^2 t + \sinh^2 t } \, dt$$
$$L(\mathrm C(T)) = \int_0^T \sqrt{ \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t } \, dt$$

Now invoke the identities $\sin^2t+\cos^2t = 1$ **but** $\sinh^2t+\cosh^2t = \exp2t-\sinh(t)\cosh(t)$ and you will see that

$$L(\mathrm C(T)) = \int_0^T \sqrt{ 1 } \, dt = t\bigr|_0^T = T$$

$$\begin{align}
L(\mathrm H(T)) &= \int_0^T \sqrt{ e^{2x} - {e^x-e^{-x}\over2} \cdot {e^x+e^{-x}\over2} } \, dt \\[2ex]
&= \int_0^T \sqrt{ e^{2x} - {e^{2x}-1-1-e^{-2x}\over4} } \, dt \\[2ex]
&= \int_0^T \sqrt{ {4e^{2x} - e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}\over4} } \, dt \quad \cdots
\end{align}$$

Does that help you see why the nice relationship seen between $t$ and $L(\mathrm C(T))$ does not emerge with $t$ and $L(\mathrm H(T))$?