# Why is sinh called "sinus hyperbolicus" despite being just a regular e function?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

What does the sinus hyperbolicus have to do with the sinus? Their graphs do not look alike at all.

The only similarity I can find is that their exponential representation looks similar.

$sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$

$sinh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{x}-e^{-x})$

Comment: Also note the relation $$ i\sin(x) = \sinh(ix). $$

Comment: See [Hyperbolic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Comparison_with_circular_functions).

Comment: See [Vincenzo Riccati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenzo_Riccati), [Opuscula physico-mathematica, Vol.1 (1757)](https://books.google.it/books?id=X8tGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA70) page 70 : "ita in hyperbola sumemus sinus et cosinus logarithmorum, quos *sinus* et *cosinus hyperbolicos* appellabimus."

Comment: Well, I don’t know whether this helps, but the standard formulas for spherical trigonometry are mirrored by formulas in hyperbolic trigonometry by the replacement of the sine and cosine by the corresponding hyperbolic functions, when it’s a matter of side lengths. For instance, the spherical Pythagorean formula is $\cos c=\cos a\cos b$, while the corresponding hyperbolic formula is $\cosh c=\cosh a\cosh b$.

Comment: See ["Geometric construction of hyperbolic trigonometric functions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451034/409). In particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/451372/409).