# What connection do the hyperbolic trig functions have to the actual trig functions?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

As far as my understanding goes, trigonometry is the math of right triangles. Sine is the opposite side over the hypotenuse, cosine is the adjacent side over the hypotenuse, etc. The unit circle definition comes as a result of this fact.

> What connection do the the hyperbolic trig functions have to the actual trig functions?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function): "Just as the points ($\cos t, \sin t$) form a circle with a unit radius, the points ($\cosh t, \sinh t$) form the right half of the equilateral hyperbola. The hyperbolic functions take a real argument called a hyperbolic angle. The size of a hyperbolic angle is twice the area of its hyperbolic sector. The hyperbolic functions may be defined in terms of the legs of a right triangle covering this sector."

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Geometric construction of hyperbolic trigonometric functions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451034/409). Also, ["Alternative definition of hyperbolic cosine without relying on exponential function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757091/409); in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409).

Comment: I think this question is addressing the direct relationship more than the similarities in their connection the either the unit circle or the parabola.

Comment: @burt: You *think*? It's your question; don't you *know*? :)  ... In any case, since comments are easily overlooked (and sometimes hidden), please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3329525/edit) to make any clarifications.

Comment: @burt In that case [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function): "The Gudermannian function, named after Christoph Gudermann (1798–1852), relates the circular functions and hyperbolic functions without explicitly using complex numbers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$ and $\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$.  Beyond that, most of the hyperbolic trig identities have a similar form compared to their "circle" trig counterparts.  For instance,

$$\sinh(x+y)=\sinh x\cosh y+\cosh x+\sinh y$$
$$\cosh^2x-\sinh^2=1 $$

Also, as noted in the comments and on Wikipedia, there is a connection to the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ analogous to the unit circle.

Comment: That is: $\sin$ and $\sinh$ are the same complex function, up to some rotations of the complex plane.  Same for $\cos$ and $\cosh$.