# Confusion surrounding the geometric definitions of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-functions

$\cos x$ and $\sin x$ can be defined by rotating $x$ units around a unit circle: $\cos x$ is the $x-$coordinate and $\sin x$ the $y$-coordinate. However, I am struggling to understand the analogous definition for $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$. I understand that a hyperbola can be defined as the set of all points satisfying $(\cosh t,\sinh t)$. However, this still begs the question as to how one can *work out* what $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$ are in the first place. I know that the hyperbolic functions can be defined using exponentials, but I think a geometric interpretation would be nice.

Comment: Isn't this about $x$ and $y$ coordinates of points swept out on a hyperbola, with some suitable choice of parametrization?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on hyperbolic functions explains the geometric interpretation. It's a little odd that the argument is an area, but in hyperbolic geometry area and angle are related.

Comment: @brainjam It's also more natural to define radians in terms of area rather than angles.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Alternative definition of hyperbolic cosine without relying on exponential function"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757091/409). See, in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409). You may also be interested in the figures shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/451372/409).