# How to explain why line intersecting hyperbola and tangent intersection meet at Y coordinate?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

I am missing some fundamental hyperbola geometry-related concepts probably and I cannot get more insight from the websites, so I'd like to ask the following from this forum.

Let `A = x(A)`, `B = Length(B)`, and `C = y(C)`

Is there any neat way to explain, why the run and the rise line `B/A` (`x = yB/A`) intersecting hyperbola (`y^2-x^2 = A^2`) and the tangent of the circle with the radius `A` meet at the Y-coordinate on point `C`? Should be also said that the tangent crosses the x-axis in `x=B`.

I can see how the math equates, but I feel I have not understood why seemingly different geometric constructions yield the same position on the Y-axis. Is this due to some explicit mathematical theorem?

Below is the construction. Pardon me for not providing more code at this point:

[image: Hyperbola tangent]

The line and the hyperbola is solved in the picture `C = AB/sqrt(B^2-A^2)`.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is very unclear. You don't say how you define your hyperbola .... I don't understand what is "the line B/A" you are speaking about ? Do you mean with equation y=(B/A)x ? Moreover $C$ means two different things a point and an expression, no in fact two expressions : which one is the good one ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried to elaborate on various parts of the question. Let me know if there is something else required.

Comment: This might relate to the two concentric circles with a tangent to the inner circle scenario. I have also found that the parabola x = y² sqrt((x(C))² - (x(B))²) gives the same focal point in Y-axis.

Comment: Moreover, I think, this is what I was looking for, hyperbolic functions and their relation to trigonometric counterparts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451034/geometric-construction-of-hyperbolic-trigonometric-functions