# Geometrical derivation of angle addition formulae in hyperbolic trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

The angle addition formulas in “regular” trigonometry state that

$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta + \cos\alpha\sin\beta$

and

$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$

It is fairly straightforward and easy to derive these formulas from a figure like this:

[image: angle addition proof]

It is also easy to prove it using:

$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}2$

and

$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Similar relations hold for the hyperbolic trig functions, namely

$\sinh(\alpha+\beta)=\sinh\alpha\cosh\beta + \cosh\alpha\sinh\beta$

$\cosh(\alpha+\beta)=\cosh\alpha\cosh\beta + \sinh\alpha\sinh\beta$

which again can be computed using

$\cosh(x) = \frac{e^{x} + e^{-x}}2$

$\sinh(x) = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}2$

How would one prove the angle sum formulas for the hyperbolic functions from [their geometric definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321343/372984)?

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit to your question. I think it makes it easier to have all the relevant information included in the post itself, so people don't have to follow links to images or look up the addition formulas.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that the argument of a hyperbolic function in the geometric definition is interpreted as an area, and it is very hard to visually see that two given areas are the same. So I doubt there will be an easy way to visualize this relationship.

Comment: Just as an FYI: [My answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409) derives the exponential formulas for $\sinh u$ and $\cosh u$ from the geometric definitions (using a pinch of Calculus).